# Break array into multiple arrays based on threshold

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have the following graph, which is a representation of an array `[2,8,12,5,3,...]`. X axis is in seconds. I want to break this array into multiple parts when y values **stays 0 for longer than 2 seconds**. So the array in this example would break into 3 parts: `x = 0 to 8`, `x = 8 to 13` and `x = 13 to 20` because y stays = 0 for more than 2 seconds from 8 to 13. In practice this array could be huge. What would be fastest method to do this in pure javascript (or if needed lodash/underscore)? Currently I am looping through this array to mark 2 second stop times. Is there a better way of doing this?

[image: Area plot]

Comment: maybe you add your code as well as some data input and wanted output.

Comment: to split the array you need both x and y... something like `[{x: 0, y: 2}, ..... ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an iterative approach with one loop while checking the expected zero value and decide if the threshold is reached or not. of not, then delete the last interval and append the length to the array before.

This proposal yields

- with `threshold = 2`:

  > ```
  > [
  >     [ 1,  7],
  >     [ 8, 13],
  >     [14, 20]
  > ]
  > ```
- with `threshold = 7`:

  > ```
  > [
  >     [ 1, 20]
  > ]
  > ```

```js
var y = [2, 8, 12, 5, 3, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 8, 10, 8, 10],
    x = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20],
    threshold = 2,
    isZero = false;
    result = [];

y.forEach(function (a, i) {
    var last = result[result.length - 1];

    if ((a === 0) !== isZero) {
        if (last) {
            last[1] = x[i];
        }
        return;
    }
    isZero = !isZero;
    if (last && isZero && x[i] - last[0] < threshold) {
        result.pop();
        if (result[result.length - 1]) {
            result[result.length - 1][1] = x[i];
        }
        return;
    }
    result.push([x[i]]);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Great solution! But shouldn't the result be `[
    [ 1,  7],
    [ 8, 13],
    [14, 20]
]` ? But let me check your solution carefully again.

Comment: you are right, i delete the answer and give you tomorrow the right answer.

Comment: Hi Nina, I see that you have changed your solution. But your solution is giving `[
  [
    1,
    8
  ],
  [
    8,
    13
  ],
  [
    13,
    20
  ]
]` when it should be `[ [ 1, 7], [ 8, 13], [14, 20] ]`. I have made a fiddle based on your solution, could you please check it out? https://jsfiddle.net/7ymkqvLa/

Comment: But with my fiddle I found one more error. The edge on the beginning. If the first y value is 0, new arrays ignore this value. And the edge on the end, gives one extra array. https://jsfiddle.net/abkrerdn/

Comment: that is, why i always ask for data and result. please add the data to the question. in the questin, you write 0-8, 8-13, 13-20 ...

Answer (score 2):

You'll always need to look at the values of the array, so you won't be able to get further than an O(n) solution. The most efficient would probably be to run through the array with a variable containing the amount of zeros you've passed through at a certain point.

The function below is a hastily made implementation of this. I've also used a variable to store the previous index. This could also be calculated from the split array, but that would be rather inefficient if you're really talking about huge arrays.

```js
function splitArray(array, treshold) {
  var zeros = 0,
      previousIdx = 0,
      splitArrays = [];
  array.forEach(function(point, idx) {
    if (point === 0) {
      zeros++;
      if (zeros == treshold && previousIdx != idx - treshold + 1) {
        splitArrays.push(array.slice(previousIdx, idx - treshold + 1));
        previousIdx = idx - treshold + 1;
      }
    } else if (zeros >= treshold) {
      splitArrays.push(array.slice(previousIdx, idx));
      previousIdx = idx;
      zeros = 0;
    }
  });
  if (previousIdx != array.length -1) {
    splitArrays.push(array.slice(previousIdx));
  }
  return splitArrays;
}
```

I've created a JSFiddle that shows this function in action with some test data: https://jsfiddle.net/Glodenox/La8m3du4/2/

I don't doubt this code can still be improved though.

If you just want to get the indices of the sections instead of an array with all data in separate arrays, you can replace the three `array.slice(a, b)` statements with `[a, b-1]`.

Comment: Great concept! But my only concern is that this disregards the x values, or assumes there is y value for every x value if I am not mistaken? But it is a great work regardless and I will try to change this a bit to consider x values.

Comment: I assumed that the x values could just be the index of the array and that this was data that indeed always had data for every second based on the example given. If the input data is in the format `[{x:1,y:1}, {x:2,y:6}, ...]`, you'd just need to adjust `point` to `point.x`. Though you'd also need to up the zeros more than just one if there are gaps in the data.